# How can I force Zabbix to warn about disaster alert after 4 attemps?

Tags: networking, monitoring, zabbix, alerts

I use Zabbix 3.4 and I am trying to configure Zabbix to send an alarm **only after 4 attemps**. This alarm checks if the HTTP server returns 200 code. 
I have tried to set up a Web Scenario, but in the Zabbix Docs they say this:

> The number of attempts for executing web scenario steps. In case of network problems (timeout, no connectivity, etc) Zabbix can repeat executing a step several times. The figure set will equally affect each step of the scenario. Up to 10 attempts can be specified, default value is 1.
>   Note: Zabbix will not repeat a step because of a wrong response code or the mismatch of a required string.
>   This parameter is supported starting with Zabbix 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted section is about retrying inside the web scenario. You will have to use trigger functions.

Checking the return code item, you can use in the expression `count(#4,200)=0`.

While this question is a bit different, the ultimate solution is the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605281/how-to-teach-zabbix-to-be-smart-about-short-spikes-in-events .

Comment: In the zabbix docummentation, says that #4 is for **number of seconds**, not for number of attempts

Comment: It most likely does not state that - can you please quote the section which you interpret like that?

Comment: count (sec|#num,<pattern>,<operator>,<time_shift>)
 Number of values within the defined evaluation period.  sec or #num - evaluation period in seconds or in latest collected values (preceded by a hash mark)
pattern (optional) - required pattern

Comment: Right, so it is the "period in seconds" normally (if it is just a number), or the number of the values (if "preceded by a hash mark") - that should match your requirement.